# Problems with Node.js and postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

I'm doing an app with express in node. I thought about different DBMS before coming up with  the idea of using PostgreSQL (I haven't got any NoSQL experience) but it's bugging me out due to some unexpected errors.

I'm trying to check if a user exist when he logs, but the Select statement doesn't work, don't know why:

```
var query = client.query('SELECT "name" FROM "User" WHERE "pass" = $1',  [req.body.password]);
console.log(query.toString());
query.on('row', function(row) {
    console.log('user "%s"', row.name);
});
```

After this the initial page should render (that actually works). I'm using the `node-postgres` driver, by the way.

If I put something like `client.query('SELECT * FROM "User"');` the database works perfectly (and I don't need that behaviour  either). I've read about the PostgreSQL identifier problems, but nevertheless it keeps happening.

Comment: You should put the variable in single quotes.

Comment: @Jakub, putting in single quotes `var query = client.query("SELECT 'name' FROM 'User' WHERE 'pass' = $1",  [req.body.password]);` gives me a syntax error in 'User', don't know why.

@mu, the docs of the [driver](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Prepared-Statements) state how prepared statements (excuse the repetition) work.

Comment: name tables must be in double quotes, strings in single quotes. So you should escape the quote. You could also do double dollar quote (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/6ccc5/1108).

Comment: If your identifiers are all legal, lower-case names, you don't need *any* quotes around them. Double quotes are only required for otherwise illegal (or not all lower-case) names. I don't see the error message you get in your question. Where is it?

Comment: The error is `error: relation "User" does not exist`. It does exist, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turns out user table exists, and the table I created is case sensitive. It works know.

I tried `select * from user` on psql and it returned the current user. Tried `select * from "User"` and turned out I was wrong. Funny thing.